# Populate textboxes based on Combobox value

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

I am trying to populate a textbox based on the selection i made on the combobox. It would basically look up the combobox value and return the assigned value from the column (the 3rd) I chose. I have some code done but it returns a type mismatch error

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
ComboBox1.List = Sheets(1).Range("C15:C39").Value
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
TextBox1.Text = Application.VLookup(ComboBox1.Value, Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A15:K39"), 3, False)
End Sub
```

Can anyone let me know what's wrong and if there is a better way to go about this?

Comment: The value being looked-up should be in the first column of your lookup table.  Also - are `Sheets(1)` and `Worksheets("sheet1")` the same sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your combo is not multiselect then load it with all of your range and just show the columns you are interested in. Make the number of columns in the ComboBox the same number of columns in your range.

```
ComboBox1.List = Sheets(1).Range("A15:K39").Value
ComboBox1.ColumnCount=11
ComboBox.ColumnWidths="0,0,100,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0"
TextBox1.Value=ComboBox1.List(ComboBox.ListIndex,2) 'the columns are zero-based
```

Answer (score 0):

Try maybe this:

```
TextBox1.Text = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ComboBox1.List(ComboBox1.ListIndex, 0), Range("C15:K39"), 1, False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys,
I ended up going with this

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim myRange As Range, f As Range

    Set myRange = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:B26")

    Set f = myRange.Find(What:=ComboBox1.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False) '<--| try and find combobox selected value
    If f Is Nothing Then
        TextBox1.Value = ""
    Else '<--| ... otherwise...
        TextBox1.Value = f.Offset(, 1)
        TextBox2.Value = f.Offset(, 2)
        TextBox3.Value = f.Offset(, 3)
    End If
End Sub
```

I had 3 textboxes that i populated with three different columns once an option is chosen from the Combobox.

What i am trying to do is have two last textboxes that I would eventually write numbers in and that would automatically update the corresponding cells.

The Problem I face is updating the cell that relates to the value entered on the combobox.
The code below is very rudimentary and i am wondering if i should do the same manually. First part of the code populates three first textboxes, second part is supposed to populate corresponding cells with value I enter depending on the combobox selection. Please let me know if i am not clear enough.

```
Private Sub OK_Click()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C9") = TextBox4.value
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D9") = TextBox5.value
End Sub
```